# Rendering from two cameras at the same time in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

the recent v0.3.0 blog post mentions WebVR 1.0 support allowing "us to have different content on the desktop display than the headset, opening the door for asynchronous gameplay and spectator modes."  This is precisely what I'm trying to get working.  I'm looking to have one camera in the scene represent the viewpoint of the HMD and a secondary camera represent a spectator of the same scene and render that view to a canvas on the same webpage.  0.3.0 removes the ability to render a-scene to a specific canvas in favor of embedded component.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish two cameras rendering a single scene simultaneously?

My intention is to have a the desktop display show what a user is doing from a different perspective.  My end goal is to be able to build a mixed reality green screen component.

Comment: Until fernandojsg gets back online and provides a more definitive answer because he has done it before, I believe it would involve a component to create a second camera/renderer/canvas and hooking into the render loop with `tick`. The default canvas will get pushed to the headset in VR mode. Then maybe adjust z-indices to show the spectator canvas on the desktop display? Just a guess.

Comment: I was able to get your suggestion working.  I'll post a github repo once I've got the kinks worked out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there may be a better or cleaner way to do this in the future, I was able to get a second camera rendering by looking at examples of how this is done in the THREE.js world.

I add a component to a non-active camera called spectator.  in the init function I set up a new renderer and attach to div outside the scene to create a new canvas.  I then call the render method inside the tick() part of the lifecycle.

I have not worked out how to isolate the movement of this camera yet.  The default look controls of the 0.3.0 aframe scene still control both camera

[image: gif of spectator cam]

Source code:
https://gist.github.com/derickson/334a48eb1f53f6891c59a2c137c180fa

Comment: You could disable look-controls on the spectator camera, or at least set `look-controls="hmdEnabled: false"`. Or hack look-controls to add a property to only listen for mouse-drag on the `canvas` rather than the `window`. It currently listens on the `window` in case you drag off canvas, but with spectator mode that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a set of components that can help with this. https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera

Here's an example showing usage with A-Frame 1.2.0 to display the main camera on the left half of the screen, and a secondary camera on the right half.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/diarmidmackenzie/aframe-multi-camera@latest/src/multi-camera.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>      
      <a-scene>
        <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1.6 0">
          <!-- first secondary camera is a child of the main camera, so that it always has the same position / rotation -->
          <!-- replace main camera (since main camera is rendered across  the whole screen, which we don't want) -->
          <a-entity
            id="camera1"
            secondary-camera="outputElement:#viewport1;sequence: replace"            
          >
          </a-entity>
        </a-entity>

        <!-- PUT YOUR SCENE CONTENT HERE-->
        

        <!-- position of 2nd secondary camera-->
        <a-entity
          id="camera2"
          secondary-camera="outputElement:#viewport2"
          position="8 1.6 -6"
          rotation="0 90 0"
        >
        </a-entity>
      </a-scene>
    </div>

    <!-- standard HTML to contrl layout of the two viewports-->
    <div style="width: 100%; height:100%; display: flex">
      <div id="viewport1" style="width: 50%; height:100%"></div>
      <div id="viewport2" style="width: 50%; height:100%"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also here as a glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/recondite-polar-hyssop

It's also been suggested that I post the entire source code for the multi-camera component here.

Here it is...

```
/* System that supports capture of the the main A-Frame render() call
   by add-render-call */
AFRAME.registerSystem('add-render-call', {

  init() {

    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.originalRender = this.el.sceneEl.renderer.render;
    this.el.sceneEl.renderer.render = this.render;
    this.el.sceneEl.renderer.autoClear = false;

    this.preRenderCalls = [];
    this.postRenderCalls = [];
    this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount = 0;
  },

  addPreRenderCall(render) {
    this.preRenderCalls.push(render)
  },

  removePreRenderCall(render) {
    const index = this.preRenderCalls.indexOf(render);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.preRenderCalls.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },

  addPostRenderCall(render) {
    this.postRenderCalls.push(render)
  },

  removePostRenderCall(render) {
    const index = this.postRenderCalls.indexOf(render);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.postRenderCalls.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
      console.warn("Unexpected failure to remove render call")
    }
  },

  suppressOriginalRender() {
    this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount++;
  },

  unsuppressOriginalRender() {
    this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount--;

    if (this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount < 0) {
      console.warn("Unexpected unsuppression of original render")
      this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount = 0;
    }
  },

  render(scene, camera) {

    renderer = this.el.sceneEl.renderer

    // set up THREE.js stats to correctly count across all render calls.
    renderer.info.autoReset = false;
    renderer.info.reset();

    this.preRenderCalls.forEach((f) => f());

    if (this.suppresssDefaultRenderCount <= 0) {
      this.originalRender.call(renderer, scene, camera)
    }

    this.postRenderCalls.forEach((f) => f());
  }
});

/* Component that captures the main A-Frame render() call
   and adds an additional render call.
   Must specify an entity and component that expose a function call render(). */
AFRAME.registerComponent('add-render-call', {

  multiple: true,

  schema: {
    entity: {type: 'selector'},
    componentName: {type: 'string'},
    sequence: {type: 'string', oneOf: ['before', 'after', 'replace'], default: 'after'}
  },

  init() {

    this.invokeRender = this.invokeRender.bind(this);

  },

  update(oldData) {

    // first clean up any old settings.
    this.removeSettings(oldData)

    // now add new settings.
    if (this.data.sequence === "before") {
        this.system.addPreRenderCall(this.invokeRender)
    }

    if (this.data.sequence === "replace") {
        this.system.suppressOriginalRender()
    }

    if (this.data.sequence === "after" ||
        this.data.sequence === "replace")
     {
      this.system.addPostRenderCall(this.invokeRender)
    }
  },

  remove() {
    this.removeSettings(this.data)
  },

  removeSettings(data) {
    if (data.sequence === "before") {
        this.system.removePreRenderCall(this.invokeRender)
    }

    if (data.sequence === "replace") {
        this.system.unsuppressOriginalRender()
    }

    if (data.sequence === "after" ||
        data.sequence === "replace")
     {
      this.system.removePostRenderCall(this.invokeRender)
    }
  },

  invokeRender()
  {
    const componentName = this.data.componentName;
    if ((this.data.entity) &&
        (this.data.entity.components[componentName])) {
        this.data.entity.components[componentName].render(this.el.sceneEl.renderer, this.system.originalRender);
    }
  }
});

/* Component to set layers via HTML attribute. */
AFRAME.registerComponent('layers', {
    schema : {type: 'number', default: 0},

    init: function() {

        setObjectLayer = function(object, layer) {
            if (!object.el ||
                !object.el.hasAttribute('keep-default-layer')) {
                object.layers.set(layer);
            }
            object.children.forEach(o => setObjectLayer(o, layer));
        }

        this.el.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
            setObjectLayer(this.el.object3D, this.data);
        });

        if (this.el.hasAttribute('text')) {
            this.el.addEventListener("textfontset", () => {
                setObjectLayer(this.el.object3D, this.data);
            });
        }
    }
});

/* This component has code in common with viewpoint-selector-renderer
   However it's a completely generic stripped-down version, which
   just delivers the 2nd camera function.
   i.e. it is missing:
   - The positioning of the viewpoint-selector entity.
   - The cursor / raycaster elements.
*/

AFRAME.registerComponent('secondary-camera', {
    schema: {
        output: {type: 'string', oneOf: ['screen', 'plane'], default: 'screen'},
        outputElement: {type: 'selector'},
        cameraType: {type: 'string', oneOf: ['perspective, orthographic'], default: 'perspective'},
        sequence: {type: 'string', oneOf: ['before', 'after', 'replace'], default: 'after'},
        quality: {type: 'string', oneOf: ['high, low'], default: 'high'}
    },

    init() {

        if (!this.el.id) {
          console.error("No id specified on entity.  secondary-camera only works on entities with an id")
        }

        this.savedViewport = new THREE.Vector4();
        this.sceneInfo = this.prepareScene();
        this.activeRenderTarget = 0;



        // add the render call to the scene
        this.el.sceneEl.setAttribute(`add-render-call__${this.el.id}`,
                                     {entity: `#${this.el.id}`,
                                      componentName: "secondary-camera",
                                      sequence: this.data.sequence});

        // if there is a cursor on this entity, set it up to read this camera.
        if (this.el.hasAttribute('cursor')) {
          this.el.setAttribute("cursor", "canvas: user; camera: user");

          this.el.addEventListener('loaded', () => {
                this.el.components['raycaster'].raycaster.layers.mask = this.el.object3D.layers.mask;

                const cursor = this.el.components['cursor'];
                cursor.removeEventListeners();
                cursor.camera = this.camera;
                cursor.canvas = this.data.outputElement;
                cursor.canvasBounds = cursor.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                cursor.addEventListeners();
                cursor.updateMouseEventListeners();
            });
        }

        if (this.data.output === 'plane') {
          if (!this.data.outputElement.hasLoaded) {
            this.data.outputElement.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
              this.configureCameraToPlane()
            });
          } else {
            this.configureCameraToPlane()
          }
        }
    },

    configureCameraToPlane() {
      const object = this.data.outputElement.getObject3D('mesh');
      function nearestPowerOf2(n) {
        return 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(n);
      }
      // 2 * nearest power of 2 gives a nice look, but at a perf cost.
      const factor = (this.data.quality === 'high') ? 2 : 1;

      const width = factor * nearestPowerOf2(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio);
      const height = factor * nearestPowerOf2(window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio);

      function newRenderTarget() {
        const target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width,
                                                   height,
                                                   {
                                                      minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                                                      magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                                                      stencilBuffer: false,
                                                      generateMipmaps: false
                                                    });

         return target;
      }
      // We use 2 render targets, and alternate each frame, so that we are
      // never rendering to a target that is actually in front of the camera.
      this.renderTargets = [newRenderTarget(),
                            newRenderTarget()]

      this.camera.aspect = object.geometry.parameters.width /
                           object.geometry.parameters.height;

    },

    remove() {

      this.el.sceneEl.removeAttribute(`add-render-call__${this.el.id}`);
      if (this.renderTargets) {
        this.renderTargets[0].dispose();
        this.renderTargets[1].dispose();
      }

      // "Remove" code does not tidy up adjustments made to cursor component.
      // rarely necessary as cursor is typically put in place at the same time
      // as the secondary camera, and so will be disposed of at the same time.
    },

    prepareScene() {
        this.scene = this.el.sceneEl.object3D;

        const width = 2;
        const height = 2;

        if (this.data.cameraType === "orthographic") {
            this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 1000 );
        }
        else {
            this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 1000);
        }

        this.scene.add(this.camera);
        return;
    },

    render(renderer, renderFunction) {

        // don't bother rendering to screen in VR mode.
        if (this.data.output === "screen" && this.el.sceneEl.is('vr-mode')) return;

        var elemRect;

        if (this.data.output === "screen") {
           const elem = this.data.outputElement;

           // get the viewport relative position of this element
           elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
           this.camera.aspect = elemRect.width / elemRect.height;
        }

        // Camera position & layers match this entity.
        this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition(this.camera.position);
        this.el.object3D.getWorldQuaternion(this.camera.quaternion);
        this.camera.layers.mask = this.el.object3D.layers.mask;

        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        if (this.data.output === "screen") {
          // "bottom" position is relative to the whole viewport, not just the canvas.
          // We need to turn this into a distance from the bottom of the canvas.
          // We need to consider the header bar above the canvas, and the size of the canvas.
          const mainRect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

          renderer.getViewport(this.savedViewport);

          renderer.setViewport(elemRect.left - mainRect.left,
                               mainRect.bottom - elemRect.bottom,
                               elemRect.width,
                               elemRect.height);

          renderFunction.call(renderer, this.scene, this.camera);
          renderer.setViewport(this.savedViewport);
        }
        else {
          // target === "plane"

          // store off current renderer properties so that they can be restored.
          const currentRenderTarget = renderer.getRenderTarget();
          const currentXrEnabled = renderer.xr.enabled;
          const currentShadowAutoUpdate = renderer.shadowMap.autoUpdate;

          // temporarily override renderer proeperties for rendering to a texture.
          renderer.xr.enabled = false; // Avoid camera modification
          renderer.shadowMap.autoUpdate = false; // Avoid re-computing shadows

          const renderTarget = this.renderTargets[this.activeRenderTarget];
          renderTarget.texture.encoding = renderer.outputEncoding;
          renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget);
          renderer.state.buffers.depth.setMask( true ); // make sure the depth buffer is writable so it can be properly cleared, see #18897
          renderer.clear();

          renderFunction.call(renderer, this.scene, this.camera);

          this.data.outputElement.getObject3D('mesh').material.map = renderTarget.texture;

          // restore original renderer settings.
          renderer.setRenderTarget(currentRenderTarget);
          renderer.xr.enabled = currentXrEnabled;
          renderer.shadowMap.autoUpdate = currentShadowAutoUpdate;

          this.activeRenderTarget = 1 - this.activeRenderTarget;
        }
    }
});
```